# How can I do when button focus on image another image appear

Tags: android

I already have designed menu bar circle layout and wheel menu for android application. it is scroll circle . But I want this

1) When button comes on image ( focus red circle ) it should be clickable

2) when button hover on image ( focus red circle ) it should be show another image

how can I understand which button focus on image.

**I put picture.First picture; when button two hovering red circle second picture appear, and another image showing. Which library should I use. Do you know any project open source code?**

sorry my bad english.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you used any libary for such design?

Comment: have a look at [here](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout).

Comment: yes I used gama-wheel.jar Thanks for answer but it is html.. I want to android example. And my project turn round. Your example is said when click button showing something. But I want when button turn around (circle) it should show image on hover to another image

Comment: Oppss... Sorry...was wrong link..chk now..

Comment: [Check this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072692/a-circular-layout-with-scrollable-contents-in-it)

Comment: where you want to show image on hover??

Comment: I show but I already designed circle layout and wheel menu. I want when button scrolling red circle it should show another image

Comment: You can change it in code using the event..Did you try???

Comment: I can not do.. :(( I want when button focus on red circle it should showing another image.But which image focus How can I separate I can not do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47817/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-duygu)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arcMenu or the android Clickwheel layouts.

Check thse links for additional details:

[ArcMenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu)

[ClickWheel](https://github.com/VadimDev/android-seekbar-like-ipod-clickwheel)

Comment: but I can do circle layout.. I want when image comes circle it should be click able..